# How to access a remote redux form state in another component

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, redux, redux-form

I have a component where in there's a Redux Form and some div section present. That div section or component I want to show only when that redux form is dirty. I don't have access to that redux form properties outside it. 
What's the right way to solve it? One way is to access the form state from the actual redux state and grab the flags from there. Is there any other way too?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of props you can use, for example [anyTouched](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/props.md/#-code-anytouched-boolean-code-) or you can even access each individual input's value using [formValues](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/formvalues.md/) and [formValueSelector](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/formvalueselector.md/)

Comment: The thing is anyTouched prop only comes when there's a validation error on a field. I want to access the dirty property on the redux Form level. There's limited information stored in the state apparently.